# How can I tell Jenkins to build the latest stable release of OWASP ZAP

Tags: jenkins, owasp, zap

I've been assigned the task of setting up a Jenkins pipeline which will run the OWASP ZAP security scanner on my company's main platform. As part of the automation, we want it to always use the latest stable release. Namely the tarball download on this page: https://www.zaproxy.org/download/

Right now I've got it to install version 2.9.0 using the custom tool addon and giving it the url https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/releases/download/v2.9.0/ZAP_2.9.0_Linux.tar.gz and subdirectory ZAP_2.9.0

If you look at the download page listed earlier, right at the bottom it says

> We maintain a page containing XML with links to the latest ZAP release files

But I don't see how to use it to grab the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

For automation I tend to use docker - the ZAP stable docker image is https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/zap2docker-stable
Alternatively you can read the XML file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zaproxy/zap-admin/master/ZapVersions.xml then extract the ZAP/core/linux/url element which is currently https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/releases/download/v2.9.0/ZAP_2.9.0_Linux.tar.gz